# How to view soap request based on webservice url?

Tags: jquery, soap, reporting-services, web-services

I need to call SSRS Report WebService using jQuery ajax request. Since the ssrs webservice is SOAP based and considering the example shown for ["calling share point web services using jquery"](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-web-services-with-jquery.aspx) I think I need to pass a soap envelope.

Based on the ssrs webservice url how can i find out the soap envelope required by a particular method?  (except fiddler)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at the wsdl file! wsdl file explains it all!